# Where do I paste "-nointro", to skip ATS's all splash screens?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I'm trying to apply [this Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/270880/discussions/0/412447331650115950/) advice. I don't see "SET LAUNCH OPTIONS"?

[image]

Comment: whoever downvoting all my questions, pls explain why. sry if i posted too many. i got no more. i usually don't have time to play ats, but when i do today, all these issues came up!

Comment: You probably got downvoted here because a) you posted a picture of text instructions instead of the text and b) you didn’t follow those instructions and right-clicked on your desktop shortcut instead

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this.

#### 1. Shortcut

- Create a shortcut of the executable (it appears you already have one).
- Right click on the shortcut, select "Properties", then switch to the "Shortcut" tab.

  [image: Screenshot of Properties window]
- Add the option to "Target". In this case, replace `-option` with `-nointro`. If you need to enter more than one option, make sure each option is separated by a whitespace.
- Make sure there is a whitespace between the path to the executable, and the option. It is possible the path is wrapped between quote marks ("). This is necessary if the path itself contains whitespaces. In this case, the "Target" would look like this:
  `"C:\Games\Quake 2 RTX\q2rtx.exe" -option`

#### 2. Set Launch Options

If you're launching games directly from Steam or are using shortcuts created by Steam, this is the only option you have. From what I've seen, Steam does not synchronize Launch Options between devices, so there's no other reason to choose this way (besides preference, convenience, habit, etc).

- In Steam, right-click on the game and select "Properties..."

  [image: Screenshot of game context menu]
- Click on "SET LAUNCH OPTIONS..."

  [image: Screenshot of game Properties window]
  [image: Screenshot of "Set Launch Option" window]
- Enter your option in the next window. In this case, replace `-option` with `-nointro`. If you need to enter more than one option, make sure each option is separated by a whitespace.